# How do I solve this problem in my ubuntu command line?

Tags: ubuntu, github

I'm new to here, please excuse me for my mistakes.

I want to push my data to github, but facing below error. Please someone consider that in my command line not generate pull command. therefore please consider this question.

This is Linux/ubuntu os and when I pull my web site into github, I see below error.

fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

and then push using the remote name

```
git push <name>
```

Could someone guide me with a step by step solution for my question?

Comment: You have the exact solution already. It's in the text that you pasted in that starts with *fatal:* and goes to the `git push <name>` line. What good would it do for us to repeat what you've already been told? *Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure the remote repository using* the commands it told you to use for that purpose. All of that information is given to you in the error message, but it only works if you read the words in the message.

Comment: Are you trying to create a local repo and push to github or you already have your code in github and want to push changes?

Comment: @mohana first option

Comment: Check https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/ for step by step guide. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/#platform-linux for step by step guide.

Hope this helps.